# Complex presentation logic same as domain logic in layered application

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I write layered application with complex domain under the hood. On the server side, there is a complex class document with, for example, Price attribute. Price is calculated by strategy-pattern classes like ManualEnteredPrice, DistributedPrice, DiscountedPrice and others.
In unit-tests, everything is OK, price is calculated, documents load and store in the database and so on.
Now I would write rich client (winforms) and web portal (javascript) for manipulating documents. I use DataTransferObjects for projects and pass data through WCF from the service layer for the client. In client, I build some kind of viewmodels (bindings in forms and knockout in web) from data transfer objects. And I have to write again the price calculation logic for presentation purpuses. Some radiobuttons for strategy choosing, some controls for data entering and similar Price-strategy-classes for calculating price to display it. And then, when I pass DTO back to the server, I don't use calculated price, because I cannot trust to its value. I must fill some fields in the document and recalculate Price again.
So, I have two different class hierarchies, doing the same things - price calculation.

Is this a correct? Maybe there is another approach? This is very often the situation, when same logic is in the domain and on the client. How do you project this architecture?

I cannot reuse domain in client, because client's classes have some differing fields or additional fields or behavior.

I cannot pass only price calculation to the service layer, because it depends on document state, status, many other document contents. Should I pass whole document for price recalculation to service and then receive and set price in viewmodel?

How do you implement the presentation logic, that is same as domain logic?

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the right approach. As you probably understand, making an architecture decision has some trade-offs. Following this specific approach, you have many benefits (data integrity, separation of concerns, minimum code dependencies etc). On the other hand, you repeat a lot of logic and you think that perhaps this is not very easy maintainable.

I would choose to follow your approach because I suppose that the only dependency between the layers is **logical**. This **logical** dependency cannot be thrown away. On the other hand, following your architecture has minimized the **code** dependencies, which is the **primary concern of any software development architecture**.

Hope I helped!

Comment: But i believe, there is some approaches, that could extend this architecture with code reusing aspects, so we can maintain application logic and keep it consistent with lesser effort and with lesser bugs.
And thank you for grammar corrections, unfortunately, my english is not good.